# Why airflow shows me a list of many connections?

Tags: airflow

I did `airflow resetdb` and I am starting all over.

Why does it show me this huge list?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing are the default, example connections.

You can delete all unwanted ones.